# AppSync DynamoDB atomic append to existing list attribute and other list operations

Tags: list, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

We have an object in dynamoDB with the key `id` and the data below in JSON format:

We are creating, getting, and updating into this table through our frontend application using Amplify API connection to AppSync.

Currently when we want to add items to our `objects` list, we overwrite the entire thing, but I know that it is possible to append new items to the existing data atomically.

My extra question is if append is supported, are other list operations supported for example `splice` and how do we implement it? Do we need to change the query on client side, or appsync resolver / `graphql` schema?

Currenly I am updating my data by overwriting with a fresh copy every time using this command on the client side:

```js
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

import {
  ...
  updateTable,
  ...
} from "../graphql/mutations";

API.graphql({ query: updateTable, variables: variables })
```

Here is the data structure in dynamoDB

```json
{
 "id": "something",
 "objects": [
  [
   {
    "foo": [
     "first",
     "second"
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "end": 20
   },
   {
    "bar": [
     "third",
     "fourth"
    ],
    "start":10,
    "end": 40
   },
  ]
 ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [append an item to the end of a list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.UpdatingListElements) in an update operation with `list_append (list1, list2)`.  DynamoDB does not support other list operations. You can [access nested list items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes) by index: `set #keys[0].#status=:s`.

You would add this append logic to your AppSync resolvers.